# NSArray: add multiple objects with same value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, repeat

How can I add multiple objects to my NSArray?  Each object will have the same value.

Ex.

I want the value "SO" added to my array 10 times

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can initialize the array with a set of objects:

```
NSString * blah = @"SO";
NSArray * items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: blah, blah, nil];
```

or you can use a mutable array and add the objects later:

```
NSMutableArray * mutableItems = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    [mutableItems addObject:blah];
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use mutable arrays and also don't want to repeat your identifier *N* times, utilize that `NSArray` can be initialized from a C-style array:

```
@interface NSArray (Foo) 
+ (NSArray*)arrayByRepeatingObject:(id)obj times:(NSUInteger)t;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Foo)
+ (NSArray*)arrayByRepeatingObject:(id)obj times:(NSUInteger)t {
    id arr[t];
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<t; ++i) 
        arr[i] = obj;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr count:t];    
}
@end

// ...
NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayByRepeatingObject:@"SO" times:10]);
```

Answer (score 5):

My ¢2:

```
NSMutableArray * items = [NSMutableArray new];
while ([items count] < count)
    [items addObject: object];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add them with [`initWithObjects:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGGC) (or whichever method you prefer). An `NSArray` does not require its objects to be unique, so you can add the same object (or equal objects) multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can use array literal syntax.

`NSArray *items = @[@"SO", @"SO", @"SO", @"SO", @"SO"];`

You can access each element like `items[0];`